# CSS not loading with Ngrok and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost, web-hosting, ngrok

Hello I'm using Wordpress relative path plugin to access the website from my mobile device, but the website CSS is not loading properly. I tried different plugins but still the issue is there.
Info:

OS: `ubuntu 18.04`

WP: `5.4.2`

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADYXG.png)

[Ngrok GET requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB20l.png)

My current wp-config has:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: have you check your `site_url` in `wp-config.php` or `wp_options` table ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask again and edit your question. You're not going to get much support with such a loose question.

Comment: Possible provide site url link ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 yup, I have edited the question with my wp-config. I tried to replace the querying variable also with my actual `ngrok` link but still the site doesn't load properly

Comment: @aviboy2006 http://ccd711c88dc4.ngrok.io

Comment: add this `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/wordpress/");` because your content inside this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216389/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-abeer00).

Comment: added answer don't forget to accept and upvote answer as your have enough reputation. Thanks.  @abeer00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this :

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/wordpress/");`

Temporary can add this `http://ccd711c88dc4.ngrok.io/wordpress/` to site_url

you can see file can access using this below URL :

http://ccd711c88dc4.ngrok.io/wordpress/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.4.2

Not by this :

http://ccd711c88dc4.ngrok.io/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.4.2

Comment: upvote also if you feel this works for you @abeer00

Comment: Why this is solving the problem? Have tried it and did not succeeded to solve the problem